# What's the point of encrypting a video for DRM purposes?

Tags: video, encryption

I've been looking into securing videos, and one thing I've run into is the concept of encrypting the output of a video source file.  This happens after the user is authenticated and access granted (for example RTMPE is one of the instances of such encryption).  What I don't get is why this serves any useful point at all for DRM purposes - and I'm not talking about RTMPE in specific, I just mean encryption of any sort at all from a server to client perspective.

After all, if I am granted access to the video, and now I'm playing it and setting it to whatever the maximum resolution is, assuming different resolutions are behind different paywalls, I could just open up OBS, record my desktop at 5000 kbps, and get an amazing rip - and encryption would do absolutely nothing to hinder me, because I'm totally bypassing the fact that I can't easily download it directly.

So my question is, why bother with encryption on videos?  It wouldn't prevent automated video farming as long as proper user credentials are presented either I think?  And furthermore, there's a sort of downside in that all the encryption technologies as far as I can find available for web usage has compatibility with one device class or another, such as RTMPE not working on iOS, which is pretty well used.  I presume there would also be more battery life issues, as I tend to run out of battery much faster when playing Flash videos rather than HTML5. So, why not just authenticate and stream it straight up over, say, html5 without any encryption?

Comment: Interesting topic, you could *discuss* this at length. Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not a forum or discussion site but a place where you can ask specific programming questions.

Comment: In my opinion, it's about making it harder for non-technical minded people. I've spent a lot of time on developing a video security solution for iOS apps, and I am well aware that anyone can just capture the output (camera, jailbreak, recording output). But most people won't have the technical skills to do so. Yet security should not come in the way of the user experience ;-)

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but it still shows high in searches.

The quick answer is that most modern devices include a secure media playback path, which should ensure that the encrypted video is decoded into protected memory which is not accessible to screen capture software. You will just see a black rectangle in the playback if this is working correctly.

There are different levels of DRM protection and different capabilities on devices so there are no absolute rules, but in general modern high end devices will have this type of protection - this is why content owners and operators may not allow some content on older devices or on devices that they consider less secure.

Its worth remembering also that the encryption is a deterrent and a hurdle - it does not stop someone recording the screen with an external camera. This is where forensic watermarking and similar technologies step in.

Answer (score 1):

Video encryption is to constrain the use scenarios and specifically ensure that only the one who knows how to decrypt can play the content back. Your example of capture and re-encoding at high bitrate and close to original quality is only possible under assumptions: (a) you can screen capture (b) screen capture does have the content quality you need in resolution, in clarity, in frame rate. It is not necessarily true that these are valid assumptions and you indeed can capture the content, and then it is still a rip with a quality loss.

That is, video encryption does prevent from direct access to the content and limits ways to capture and produce derivative material, specifically prevents from being able to get a zero loss copy of unencrypted material. Video encryption however does not work alone: the playback software needs to be secure as well so that the data is not intercepted at the stage of processing from encrypted to encrypted before the actual presentation. If you can break in at this stage, the video encryption alone does not work for the intended purpose.